# Does this sentence need "me" or "I"?

Tags: prepositions, pronouns, grammatical-case

Here is the sentence.  Which one is correct?

1. Dec. 21st from 9:30-10:30 can work for both I-SHEA and I.
2. Dec. 21st from 9:30-10:30 can work for both I-SHEA and me.

I think it should be I-SHEA and me but that sounds a little odd.  Maybe that's because people usually use the wrong pronoun?

Comment: If it's just you, would you say "can work for me" or "can work for I"?

Comment: Look up "me"| after a preposition. Also, this question belongs on ELL, not here. Cheers.

Comment: @Lambie: Given that a significant minority of native speakers get this wrong (via hypercorrection), I don't think it's restricted to learners of English... I'd be surprised if there wasn't already more than one duplicate, though.

Comment: @psmears A significant number yes, get it wrong. But I hear most of them getting it wrong. So, a majority rather than a minority (at least, say, on TV).

Comment: @psmears Thank you for nailing it as *hypercorrection*.